# Is it possible to parse the branch name to create a readable comment?

Tags: bash, git

I have an alias in my .gitconfig that allows me to quickly add, commit all outstanding files and then push a PR.  I copied it from somewhere on SO probably.

```
[alias]
    lazy = "!f() { git add -A && git commit -m \"$@\" && git push; }; f"
```

This lets me do the following:

```
> git lazy "HS-123: Add logging functionality"
```

In an effort to be lazier still, I'd like to streamline it by reading name of the current branch, and parsing a commit comment out of it.  When I start work on a ticket, I create a branch name that includes the ticket number and functionality.  For instance, ticket HS-123 is adding logging functionality.  So my branch is `feature/hs-123-add-logging-functionality`.

I would like to parse the branch name to automatically create a comment like `HS-123: Add logging functionality`.  So the ticket name followed by colon, then the functionality description with dashes removed. This way, i could just type `git lazy` and be done.

I have the following questions:

1. What language is used in the alias (looks vaguely JavaScriptish or maybe bash)?
2. How do I obtain the current branch once I do know what the language is?

P.S. Thanks to this answer and some other ones, I cobbled together a script that might help others in the future.

```
[alias]
    foo =  "!f() {  : convert branch name like hotfix/hs-123-add-logging into a comment like HS-123: Add logging; \
                    : get the current branch; \
                    branch="$(git branch --show-current)"; \
                    : find the index of the forward slash; \
                    index="$(expr index "$branch" /)"; \
                    : remove everything before the forward slash leaving hs-123-add-logging; \
                    withoutEnvironment=${branch:$index}; \
                    : parse out the description only e.g. add-logging; \
                    description=${withoutEnvironment#*-*-}; \
                    : parse out the ticket number only e.g. hs-123; \
                    ticket=${withoutEnvironment%-"$description"}; \
                    : upper case the first letter of description e.g. Add-logging; \
                    description=${description^}; \
                    : replace dashes with spaces e.g. Add logging; \
                    description=${description//-/ }; \
                    : upper case the entire ticket number e.g. HS-123; \
                    ticket=${ticket^^}; \
                    separator=': '; \
                    : create a comment by combining ticket, separator and description; \
                    comment=${ticket}${separator}${description}; \
                    : git add, commit and push; \
                    git add -A && git commit -m \"${comment}\" && git push; \
                 }; f"
```

Comment: (1) Yes, the language is shell (not positive it's bash, may be locked to `/bin/sh` and thus want to aim at POSIX compliance).

Comment: ...and wrt. (2), run `git branch`?

Comment: ...the _titular_ question, beyond those two narrow items, is arguably too broad to be on-topic here; it could be argued to boil down to "please write my program for me". We have no shortage of narrower, answered questions about string processing in bash; making an effort to cobble them together would put you in a better place to ask a question about a place where you get stuck.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a way to determine whether it is bash or not?

Comment: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` -- if that's empty, it's not bash. Also, if it's bash, you can `set -o | grep posix` to see if compatibility mode is on or off.

Comment: That said, for anything with substantial logic, I'd just have the alias call an external script; that way its shebang can explicitly specify the interpreter to use so you can write your logic in whichever language you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the alias is shell.  Git invokes `/bin/sh`, which is `dash` on Debian and Ubuntu, not `bash`.  You should therefore restrict yourself to POSIX shell semantics, with the possible addition of the additional features that Debian documents in its policy manual, such as `local`.  Git will send all aliases beginning with `!` to the shell.

To obtain the branch name, you can run `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.  This is better for scripting, since `git branch` is not meant to be used in scripts.

If your goal is to write a commit message, you are probably better off putting the message editing code in a `commit-msg` hook and handling the text in a full-fledged shell script (or a script in another language).  Note that it's not a good idea to write commit messages consisting only of one line, so you will probably want to actually write some additional text in your editor.

Comment: Huh, I thought `local` was POSIX. It's in all the `/bin/sh` shells I've used on modern systems, which makes sense if it's also in dash. :-)

Comment: It isn't in POSIX, but it is in most major shells with the exception of _AT&T_ ksh.  There is a proposal to add it in the Austin Group (the folks who manage the POSIX standard).